# using git plugin on netbean

Tags: git, netbeans, assembla

I am having problem while trying to clone a PRIVATE repository from assembla. If I use command line tool, it works fine. But from inside netbean IDE, its not working. The screeshot of the settings I am providing is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone please help me finding what I am doing wrong please? Thanks.

Comment: If it helps you I'm using git in Netbeans as well and I have the same problem often. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. If I click on next button 4-5times it works. I use ssh-key instead of password.

Comment: Yeah finally got this working by ssh key pairs.

Comment: @Rana: I also have exact problem with you. I already try using ssh key pair but still return Auth fail warning. I use Putty Gen to generate ssh key. How exactly your step to make it work?